# Create variable in powershell using Remove and Insert

Tags: powershell

Given a filename of 8 characters in length, need to store the first 6 characters in a variable, then insert an underscore after the 4th character of that variable. I have the following code that works, but there must be a way to combine these two into one statement...

```
$NewFolder =  $_.Name.Remove(6)

$NewFolder = $NewFolder.Insert(4,'_')
```

Comment: `$_.name.remove(6).insert(4,'_')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `string` methods. The leftmost method will be applied first. The result of the method execution calls the second method.

```
$NewFolder = $_.Name.Remove(6).Insert(4,'_')
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another way to do the job. [*grin*] what it does ...

- grabs the first 4 chars
- grabs the next 2 chars
- ignores the remaining chars
- puts the 2 capture groups on each side of an underscore

the code ...

```
'12345678' -replace '^(.{4})(.{2}).+$', '$1_$2'
```

output = `1234_56`